# Akedah Isaac and the instruction from Hashem

Tags: binding-of-isaac

I have a query regarding Akedah.
Why is it that the first instruction to Avraham to sacrifice Isaac comes directly from Hashem, but the later instruction to stop the sacrifice comes from the Malakh (angel)? Also its the Malakh who calls the second time and blesses Avraham too.

How do we consolidate this? Why didn't Hashem himself stop Avraham & bless him later? Why do it through an angel when the first instruction is directly from Hashem. Also how does Avraham comprehend this? How does he know for sure, the angel is overiding Hashem's initial command? Also do we know who this angel was?

Thanks..

Comment: The malbim discusses it a few times throughout the perek. Here’s one instance. https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Genesis.22.14.1?lang=bi